# Error when creating a core by specifying a config directory

Tags: solr, ubuntu-14.04, apache-zookeeper

I am attempting to create a core in SolrCloud using the following command:

```
sudo /opt/solr/bin/solr create -c Collection1 -d /home/callmekatootie/Desktop/conf
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Connecting to ZooKeeper at localhost:9983 ...
Uploading /home/callmekatootie/Desktop/vm/configs for config Collection1 
to ZooKeeper at localhost:9983

Creating new collection 'Collection1' using command:
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=Collection1
&numShards=1&replicationFactor=1&maxShardsPerNode=1
&collection.configName=Collection1


ERROR: Failed to create collection 'Collection1' due to: org.apache.solr.client.
solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at 
http://127.0.1.1:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'Collection1_shard1_replica1':
Unable to create core [Collection1_shard1_replica1]
Caused by: solr.SynonymExpandingExtendedDismaxQParserPlugin
```

What is the `SynonymExpandingExtendedDismaxQParserPlugin` and why am I getting the above error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause of the issue.

Turns out that `SynonymExpandingExtendedDismaxQParserPlugin` is an actual plugin that was being used in the SolrConfig.xml present in the configuration files that I was uploading.

This plugin was available through https://github.com/healthonnet/hon-lucene-synonyms which I had to copy to `/opt/solr/server/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/` folder - I had to paste that jar file in this folder. I restarted Solr and then managed to execute the mentioned command successfully.